# Cannot find firefox binary in PATH - Setting environment Path doesn't work

Tags: c#, selenium

I had the problem saying **Cannot find firefox binary in PATH** which has solutions many times on this site. However those I found are mostly adding something specific in code (different ways) with one path. However adding firefox path in code works fine, but I need to execute it on many machines which have differents paths...

Setting it in the path system environment variable doesn't seem to work.

**How could I had it in a way that is specific to every machine?**

Note: I constantly switched beween firefox 42 and firefox 46... and then this suddenly happen. Is there a reason why it did happen when doing the same thing dozens of time worked fine?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox executable in Linux calls `firefox.sh` file. One workaround is the following:

```
locate firefox.sh|sh
```